# Was bedeutet das Wort kopfmäßig?

Tags: meaning, usage

Was bedeutet das Wort »kopfmäßig«?

Mein Freund hat mir über seine vorherige Beziehung erzählt. Er hat nur gesagt, seine Freundin war kopfmäßig. Sonst hat er nichts mehr weiter gesagt.

Comment: Der Duden weiß es: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_maeszig - ud deswegen sollte die Frage geschlossen werden.

Comment: @tofro: Aus dem, was der Duden dazu sagt, kann man nur schließen, dass »kopfmäßig« irgendwas in der Art »hat mit dem Kopf zu tun, ist mit einem Kopf vergleichbar« heißen könnte. Ich halte das für ziemlich unkonkret, weswegen ich finde, die Frage sollte durchaus offen bleiben. Das Wort wird in der von dir verlinkten Seite nicht erwähnt und hat auch keinen eigenen Eintrag im Duden. Daher halte ich es sehr wohl für legitim, danach zu fragen.

Answer (score 6):

Im gegebenen Kontext kann ich das Wort *kopfmäßig* nicht sicher zuordnen. Vermutlich ist [verkopft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verkopft) oder kopfgesteuert gemeint:

> (zu) sehr vom Intellekt beherrscht, beeinflusst

Comment: Ja, das vermuten wohl die meisten von uns. Aber reicht es eine Vermutung zu haben, um das dann als Antwort zu verkaufen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast
Da es sich bei diesem Wort anscheinend um eine Neuschöpfung handelt,
könnte wohl nur der Erfinder (also der betreffende Freund) eine
autoritative Antwort geben. Aber wenn der Satz nicht noch weiter ging
("... kopfmäßig nicht ganz normal"), fällt mir beim besten Willen
keine andere mögliche Deutung ein.

Comment: Ja eh. Mir fällt auch nichts besseres ein. Aber eben weil ich nur blind raten kann, schreib ich auch keine Antwort. Ich finde »ich weiß nichts genaues aber ich rate mal ohne echte Grundlage« ist ein bisschen dünn für eine Antwort. Denn so weit wird der Fragesteller auch selbst gekommen sein. Diese »Antwort« bringt keinen Erkenntnisgewinn für den, der gefragt hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ob der Fragesteller auch selbst so weit gekommen ist, ist mir nicht klar. (Wenn ja, dann wäre die Antwort in der Tat redundant.)

Comment: Was, außer einer Vermutung könnte Antwort zu einer Frage nach der Bedeutung eines Neologismus sein?